# Eu posso usar o Laravel 5.3 em projetos feitos em 5.2?

Tags: laravel

meu note estragou e estou montando o ambiente vagrant virtualbox em outro note.
Estava usando o Lavarel 5.2. Eu posso instalar a versão 5.3? Terei algum problema de compatibilidade com meus projetos feitos em 5.2?
Obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terá alguns problemas, pois algumas coisas mudaram, mas na codumentação do Laravel tem um guia de como realizar essa atualização, veja em: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0